# 2D collision and background music XNA 3.1

Tags: audio, background, xna, collision

I'm making a goal keeper game for my XNA assignment and I was wondering how would I write a code that will: detect that the ball has collided with the goal keeper then the ball will be reset to it's original position.
Also how would I set a song so that it will be playing in the background as soon as the program starts?

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked up this, there is tons of information on both of these subjects. Try to limit each question.. well to one question.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go :

Texture2D is a graphic container of a 2D object.
Rectangle can be used to contain the Texture.

When you construct a goalKeeper object inside a specified rectangle you can use a lot of methods for rectangles ie rectangle.intersects(theObjectYouWantToCheckIntersectFor).

So what you do is this :

```
class Ball
{
Texture2D myTexture;
Rectangle myRect;
Vector2 velocity;

public Ball(Texture2D newTexture, Rectangle newRect, Vector2 newVelocity)//Constructor 
{
myTexture = newTexture;
myRect = nwRect;
speed = newVelocity;
}

public void Intersect Check(goalKeeper checkForIntersect)//pass in the goalKeeper object
{
if(rectangle.Intersects(checkForIntersect.rectangle)
{
Ball.Vector2 = Vector.Zero; //Or whatever place you want it to default to
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the collision you just make a rectangle around your ball and the goalkeeper. Then use the rectangles intersect method to see if they are touching.

If you want a more precise collision you can check the pixels in the image and from that see if a collision have occured.

For the background music try:

LoadContent:

```
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true; 
MediaPlayer.Play(Content.Load<Song>("Directory\\songtitle"));
```